# How to visualize the K fold cross validation in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am using tensor board for visualization of the model , it is the representation of k fold cross validation and I am using 10 fold validation , I don't know about all these below lines shown in the below picture , if I use other than k fold , I just got 1 line for epoch accuracy and that simply means that accuracy is either going down or up which is easy to understand , but here I am unable to understand these lines while I using k fold .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

During a pass through each of the folds, an events.out.tfevents is created. In your case, since there are 10 folds, 10 events.out.tfevents are created and it is being plotted as a continuous value. To be able to visualize this better, you can save each fold in a new directory so that the accuracy of that particular fold gets saved in a new folder.

For example, in my case I had 5 folds which was plotted as:

[5 folds as one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4CsX.png)

So I kept track of a counter during each of the folds using a variable 'foldcount'. In the training loop, I saved the events.out.tfevents in a different folder for each of the splits i.e. run_split1, run_split2... as below

```
writer.add_scalars('runs_split{}'.format(foldcount), {'Loss/train': training_loss,
                                  'Loss/validation': validation_loss}, epoch+1)
```

This resulted in a different plot for each of the folds as below:

[One plot for each split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtyJi.png)